# Numpy Array Division

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that I am trying to divide by a number, but when I do, the array that is returned to me doesn't make sense.

Below is the array that I am dealing with:

```
 print(np.arange(1,len(df_rets)+1))
```

[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198...]

And when I divide it by a number,

```
print(np.arange(1,len(df_rets)+1))/2
```

it returns the below array. I expect all the numbers in the array to be divided by two but that isn't the case. Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

[  0   1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   6   6   7   7   8   8   9
   9  10  10  11  11  12  12  13  13  14  14  15  15  16  16  17  17  18
  18  19  19  20  20  21  21  22  22  23  23  24  24  25  25  26  26  27
  27  28  28  29  29  30  30  31  31  32  32  33  33  34  34  35  35  36
  36  37  37  38  38  39  39  40  40  41  41  42  42  43  43  44  44  45
  45  46  46  47  47  48  48  49  49  50  50  51  51  52  52  53  53  54
  54  55  55  56  56  57  57  58  58  59  59  60  60  61  61  62  62  63
  63  64  64  65  65  66  66  67  67  68  68  69  69  70  70  71  71  72
  72  73  73  74  74  75  75  76  76  77  77  78  78  79  79  80  80  81
  81  82  82  83  83  84  84  85  85  86  86  87  87  88  88  89  89  90
  90  91  91  92  92  93  93  94  94  95  95  96  96  97  97  98  98  99
  99 100 100 101 101 102 102 103 103 104 104 105 105 106 106 107 107 108
 108 109 109 110 110 111 111 112 112 113 113 114 114 115 115 116 116 117
 117 118 118 119 119 120 120 121 121 122 122 123 123 124 124 125 125 126
 126 127 127 128 128 129 129 130 130 131 131 132 132 133 133 134 134 135
 135 136 136 137 137 138 138 139 139 140 140 141 141 142 142 143 143 144
 144 145 145 146 146 147 147 148 148 149 149 150 150 151]

Thanks!

Comment: `print np.arange(1,len(df_rets)+1)/2.0` (in Python < 3  integer division gives you truncated integers)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using python 2 or python 3?  In python 3, the code you posted gives what you want (after correction of the typo.)  In python 2, you have to divide by 2.0, or you get integer division.